# Raycasting for Object Selection Inaccurate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am using a raycasting system attached to a camera in a chess game in order to determine which piece is being selected. However, when attempting to select a piece that is partially obsured by another (eg a pawn near a rook) even though I select the pawn, the rook would still be selected.

As far as I can tell there are no mesh protrusions that may be causing this and I have attempted tweaking the colliders as well (although I don't think that's what raycasting works off) to no avail. Here is the racasting code:

```
  // Builds a ray from camera point of view to the mouse position
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    // Casts the ray and get the first game object hit
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1))
        return hit.transform.gameObject;
    else
        return null;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Raycast indeed uses the colliders, if you're using bounding boxes for collision then it can hit the box even if it seems you're clicking on the other piece, if you have doubts enable the colliders rendering and see if that's the problem

Comment: Ahh... I thought it went off the meshes themselves... will see if I can adjust accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: James, use many small box colliders, to "make up" the object. That's exactly how you build games.  So, a dog might be "three boxes", you get it?  For a giraffe, you might need say seven boxes (legs, body, neck, head).  Use as many as you like, use a dozen per piece if needs be.  You'll probably use one or two capsules and one or two balls.

Comment: Ahh makes sense... Migrating from Unreal where the meshes themselves are just used as colliders by default. Useful info, thanks!